# How to do a Cross-Domain AJAX request in IE8 with Chrome Frame

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cors, google-chrome-frame

I've got an application that needs to support IE8 (with Google Chrome Frame), that will make cross-domain requests. I understand regular IE8 makes use of XDomainRequest for these calls, but when using Chrome Frame and looking through the console, I don't see XDomainRequest listed in the window object.

Since I'm using Chrome Frame, I understand I'm using the Chrome JavaScript engine... but does this mean I should be able to use XMLHTTPRequest for CORS? When I try that, I get a cross-domain error in the console.

Can someone clarify how this should be working? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 doesn't support CORS, but you can look into JSONP if you're only doing Get requests.  There are however a few security concerns with JSONP though.
Another approach is doing a reverse proxy which means you create a page/service on your own domain that in turn makes the request to the other domain. This gets around the cross domain issue since the browser requests a resource on your domain.

Comment: I'm doing POST requests unfortunately. I may have to look into the reverse proxy option, since I'm having a hard time finding viable ways of getting this to work. I'm also having a hard time believing that vanilla IE8 can make this request, but IE8 with Chrome Frame cannont.